# Routing not working in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have an angular.js controller (`loginErrorCtrl`) that is supposed to redirect to a view (`/menu`) when the data supplied from an input is equal to a specified string defined in the app (`Data.serverToken`).

```
function loginErrorCtrl($scope, Data, $location) {
  $scope.data = Data;
  $scope.validateToken = function(token) {  
    if (token != null) {
      if (token.length == 4) {
        if (token == Data.serverToken) {
          $location.path('/menu');
          } else {
          //error
          return "Invalid Token please try again";
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The problem is that, when I type the correct token into the input box the  `$location.path('/menu')` doesn't redirect until I hit the backspace. How can I get it to redirect upon successful validation of token?

Code listing on plunker : [Angular JS routing](http://plnkr.co/edit/f1viaDXqa59U2ZQakUEr)

Comment: Try adding `$scope.$apply()` after setting the path.  I didn't download your code, but it sounds like you might be calling validateToken() outside of Angular.  A keypress will trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: @MarkRajcok It still doesn't work. I get an error that says: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
    at Object.$scope.validateToken `

Comment: True, scope doesn't have an `apply` method, but it does have an `$apply` method -- you probably missed the `$`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thank you for the help. I did leave out the `$` but here is the weird part. In chrome, i get the error: `Error: $digest already in progress
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at g` until the page crashes whereas in firefox, after a slight delay, it succesfully redirects. Your mention on `$digest` has also sent me on a path on enlightenment i'm checking out this post  [Notes On AngularJS Scope Life-Cycle](http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/). If you could, please download the snippet it's just 36kb.. thanks!

Comment: don't place code in downloads... will never be looked at. Place it in question itself or put a demo together in http://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was to put the $scope.$apply() as Mark suggested
in the comments like so:

```
function loginErrorCtrl($scope, Data, $location) {
$scope.data = Data;
$scope.validateToken = function(token) {  
if (token != null) {
  if (token.length == 4) {
    if (token == Data.serverToken) {
      $location.path('/menu');
      $scope.$apply()
      } else {
      //error
      return "Invalid Token please try again";
    }
  }
}
};
}
```

[corrected code](http://plnkr.co/edit/f1viaDXqa59U2ZQakUEr?p=preview)